# I'm writing a program that compares two arrays together, but I can't get it to compare arrays with empty elements

Tags: java, arrays

My code is pasted below. The program works fine on different types of two-dimensional arrays, where if they're identical it returns "true", and if they're not it returns false. However there is a small bug when both arrays have empty elements in both their dimensions:

```
    int a[][] = {{},{}};
    int b[][] = {{},{}};
```

This input needs to return "true" since the arrays are still identical, however I'm getting an array index out of bounds error. Is there any way I can make my program recognize that these two arrays are still identical?

```
public class ArrayCompare {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a[][] = {{},{}};
        int b[][] = {{},{}};
        boolean result = equals(a,b);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static boolean equals(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        boolean boo = true;
        if (a != null && b != null) {
          if (a.length != b.length || a[0].length != b[0].length || a[1].length != b[1].length)
              boo = false;
          else
              for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                  for(int j =0; j <b.length; j++) {
                      if (b[i][j] != a[i][j]) {
                          boo = false;    
                      }   
                  }

            }
        }else {
          boo = false;
        }
        return boo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re checking `a[0].length` != `b[0].length` before you check if the arrays are empty.

Comment: is it not faster to use a join to string? So, compare the join strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this check to the `else` statement `a[i].length > 0`:

```
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].length > 0) {  // add check for empty array
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

Your code works fine with some correction. Probably I give you idea, how to improve it. What about this one:

```
public static boolean equals(int[][] one, int[][] two) {
    if (one == null || two == null || one.length != two.length)
        return false;

    for (int row = 0; row < one.length; row++) {
        if (one[row].length != two[row].length)
            return false;

        for (int col = 0; col < one[row].length; col++)
            if (one[row][col] != two[row][col])
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small logical flaw in your code. In the nested loop, you should iterate over the elements from each array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for(int j =0; j <b[i].length; j++) {// iterate over the number of elements of the current array
        if (b[i][j] != a[i][j]) {
            boo = false;
        }
    }
}
```